# Spinner.setSelected(false) and Spinner.setSelection(0,true) is working to solve null point exception except handset ex: Samsung sm-G31

Tags: android, spinner, argumentnullexception

In my android app, I was facing following error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference onItemSelected

Therefore I used `location.setSelected(false)` and `location.setSelection(0,true)` to avoid the null string. My code works perfectly on all handsets except Samsung sm-g31h, which shows the same error. Need a possible solution for that. My code is given below

**MainActivity.java**

```
 location = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    location.setPrompt("Select Location");

    location.setAdapter(
            new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                    adapter1, R.layout.location_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                    // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
                    this));
  //  location.setSelected(false);  // must
  //  location.setSelection(0,true);  //must
    location.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

location.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.w("location----", "> " + location.getSelectedItem().toString());


            location_code = location.getSelectedItem().toString();

            loc_code = location_code.substring(0, 1).toString();

            Log.e("loccode", "> " + loc_code);
            final String check =String.valueOf(loc_code);
            Log.e("checkloccode", "> " + check);

            if(loc_code.equals("S")){
                Log.e("loccodeif", "> " + check);
                location.setFocusable(true);
                location.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                location.requestFocus();


            }


            else{
                Log.e("loccodeelse", "> " + check);

                shift_spinner.setFocusable(true);
                shift_spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                shift_spinner.requestFocus();

            }






        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            return;
        }
    });
```

**NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter**

```
public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter, ListAdapter {

protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
protected Context context;
protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

/**
 * Use this constructor to have NO 'Select One...' item, instead use
 * the standard prompt or nothing at all.
 * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter.
 * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps
 * you want text grayed out like a prompt...
 * @param context
 */
public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
        int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {

    this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
}

/**
 * Use this constructor to Define your 'Select One...' layout as the first
 * row in the returned choices.
 * If you do this, you probably don't want a prompt on your spinner or it'll
 * have two 'Select' rows.
 * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter. Should probably return false for isEnabled(0)
 * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps you want
 * text grayed out like a prompt...
 * @param nothingSelectedDropdownLayout layout for your 'Select an Item...' in
 * the dropdown.
 * @param context
 */
public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
                                     int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, Context context) {
    this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
    this.context = context;
    this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
    this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // This provides the View for the Selected Item in the Spinner, not
    // the dropdown (unless dropdownView is not set).
    if (position == 0) {
        return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
    }
    return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use
    // the convertView if possible.
}

/**
 * View to show in Spinner with Nothing Selected
 * Override this to do something dynamic... e.g. "37 Options Found"
 * @param parent
 * @return
 */
protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Android BUG! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 -
    // Spinner does not support multiple view types
    if (position == 0) {
        return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ?
                new View(context) :
                getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
    }

    // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
    return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
}

/**
 * Override this to do something dynamic... For example, "Pick your favorite
 * of these 37".
 * @param parent
 * @return
 */
protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int count = adapter.getCount();
    return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position >= EXTRA ? adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA) : position - EXTRA;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return adapter.hasStableIds();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return adapter.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return position != 0; // Don't allow the 'nothing selected'
    // item to be picked.
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how did you find it duplicate ? have you read the problem? My question was about why the null point exception solution is not working in a specific handset@abdul kawaee